# Intersection of inscribed equilateral triangles in a circle

Tags: geometry, triangles, circles, area, integral-geometry

I'm trying to find a proof for this proposition, but I can't find an initial hint. Note: This proposition comes from numerical evidence (Geogebra). My first try was to use formulas from integral geometry (Crofton and Poincare Formula for convex domains), but I got stuck in the geometrical arguments about the expected intersections with lines and circles, respectively. I really think there might be an easier, clean, basic geometry way.

Let be 2 inscribed equilateral triangles in a circle. Prove that for the intersection $H$ of these triangles (an hexagon), the perimeter of $H$ multiplied by the circle diameter is 8 times the area of $H$
$$8A(H)=P(H)D$$

Solution: As Blue indicated in the comment, joining the circle center with the hexagon vertices give 6 congruent triangles. Trivially, the base of this triangle is $\frac{P(H)}{6}$ and the height is $D/4$. Therefore, $A(H)=\frac{6bh}{2}=\frac{P(H)D}{8}$

[image]

Comment: Even when you're completely stumped, you can provide useful context. If this is a textbook exercise, tell us the topic(s) covered so far that seem relevant. If it's an online challenge or a contest, give the intended audience and/or expected level of complexity of the answer. What tools are allowed? (Synthetic geometry? coordinates? trig? vectors? etc.) Sometimes, just "thinking out loud" about things you know can get you going, and it keeps others from explaining things you already understand. (Add such context to the body of the question. Comments are easily overlooked and may be hidden.)

Comment: Hi, I've added the motivation, I'm not very familiar with integral geometry formulas, but i think there might be a proof with them

Comment: The relation is valid. ... Observe that segments from the circle's center to the hexagon's vertices divide the latter into six congruent triangles, for which a "base" and "height" are easily expressible in terms of the hexagon's perimeter and circle's diameter.

Comment: I got it, it was trivial :c, thank you!

Comment: you don't need to establish that the six triangles are congruent. You only need to note that the base of each triangle is a side of $H$ and the height is $D/4$ for each triangle.

Comment: @rgvalenciaalbornoz: Please don't post solutions in the question body; instead, you can write answers to your own questions.